# Download blob data as file in MVC

Tags: c#, arrays, download, memorystream

I have a file testme.txt which has "test test test test" as text in it and I am using Oracle to retrieve the file as blob and I am using byte[] to store the data. 
The data I am getting from Oracle is "74657374207465737420746573742074657374". When I try to download this file the downloaded file has some weird symbols.
The code I've tried is

```
public ActionResult DownloadFiles(string fileSeq)
    {            
        var byteArray=byte_array_got_from_oracle;
        var stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
        return new FileStreamResult(stream, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet); //since the file could be of any type
    }
```

I've tried various ways and none seems to download the text file with the original data.

Comment: How are you getting `byte_array_got_from_oracle`?

Comment: @mason: There is a Oracle package function which returns the data as xml and I am converting that to class objects

Comment: XML? See, that doesn't sound right. That's why you need to include an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question. Your question isn't complete.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
    public ActionResult DownloadTest()
    {
        var data = new byte[] { 0x74, 0x65, 0x73, 0x74, 0x20, 0x74, 0x65, 0x73, 0x74, 0x20, 0x74, 0x65, 0x73, 0x74, 0x20, 0x74, 0x65, 0x73, 0x74 };


        return File(data, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
    }
```

And the downloaded file contains:

```
    test test test test
```

Comment: The byte array I have has values like "249, 142, 185, ..". I don't even know what these values are

Comment: It doesn't metter, the solution is to use the File(byte_array_got_from_oracle, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet) method not FileStreamResult